# Android: Add view into another while having a click listener on the parent

Tags: java, android, view, onclick, click

I am trying to achieve the following hierarchy:
GridView -> Every item is a view (let's call it 'container') that contains a background, ImageView and CheckBox.

If the user clicks on the container, it doesn't matter where, whether over the checkbox, image, or the background, the CheckBox should change it checked state.

Right now I have the following layout for it:

```
<!-- main layout -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button android:id="@+id/selectBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:minWidth="200dp" />
    <GridView android:id="@+id/imageGridView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit" android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp" android:columnWidth="90dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_above="@id/selectBtn" />
</RelativeLayout>

<!-- gallery item layout - every grid item is inflated from this -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/thumbImage" 
        android:layout_width="110dp" 
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:background="#999999"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:contentDescription="image thumb"/>
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/itemCheckBox" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

After this I want to be able to retrieve the checked containers.

I don't really know how to create this layout. Even tho my layout appears alright now, there is no 'container' that would react to click listener. I can only make the checkbox react to click, which is of course not very user-friendly. So how could I add a wrapper container around these views that would serve for clicking? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, never mind... As RelativeLayout extends View and ViewGroup, I can just use something like:

```
RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout) holder.imageview.getParent();
container.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.d("test", "clicked");
                    RelativeLayout cont = (RelativeLayout) v;
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) cont.getChildAt(1);
                    if(cb.isChecked()) cb.setChecked(false);
                    else cb.setChecked(true);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You also could use [setOnItemClickListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener%29) method of GridView to set the click listener for the item (image + checkbox). And inside your listener you can change the checked state of checkbox. 
Good luck!